# ag grid format one row as percentage & one row as decimal

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am using ag grid for the first time, it looks great. I have a table with two rows. One row shows percentage and the other row numbers with the thousand separator, example below.

```
 col1        col2      col3
 value       2,345.6   3,677.7
 percentage  13.8%     9.6%
```

How using ag grid do I format rows? I know I can format columns using the columnDefs and specifying a valueFormatter but not sure how to format rows? I can't transpose my data so that the rows become columns.

Comment: Can you post sample of your data and code you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write a single custom valueFormatter that can conditionally provide one or the other format.

The parameters to the valueFormatter give you access to the whole row, so in your case, you could check the content of the first cell of the row to determine which format to use.